# Routing of message of same message type from different receive locations in Biztalk

Tags: routes, integration, biztalk

I have a simple scenario where I have to route messages from One folder to another. Now, these messages can come from 10 different sources (folder), and are to be routed to 10 separate locations (folder).

For eg. Consider `SourceA, SourceB, SourceC`... are receive locations and `DestA, DestB, DestC`,... are destination locations.

So, file from `SourceA` is to be routed to `DestA` and so on.

Now,I have already implemented the scenario.
My question is What will be the best approach for this?

1) One receive port with 10 receive locations and the logical receive port binded with physical ports. One listen shape will listen for the message and after doing separate task, will route to corresponding location. There could be separate orchestrations as well, as specific task may have to be performed for each incoming message.

2) 10 receive locations where all the messages are published to message box and with one dynamic logical recieve port in orchestration.

The main concern is individually messages from source location should be routed to corresponding destination location only.

Note : The message type & data in these locations can be exactly same as well. So routing based on some data field is not possible.

Please let me know if you need some more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer in this case is the simplest.

- 10 Receive Ports/Locations
- 10 Send Ports

The Send Port Filter is based on BTS.ReceivePortName.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no data property to route on, you need a context property that you can route on instead. As per Johns-305 answer you can use BTS.ReceivePortName if it is messaging only with no Orchestrations.  However if you have Orchestrations you either than either have to make sure you persist the BTS.ReceivePortName or use another context property that is promoted.

The context property we prefer to use the **BTS.Operation** as this is automatically promoted, this can be set by one of the following.

- in WCF-WebHttp Receive Locations via Http Method and URL Mapping
- in WCF-WSHttp via it's operation
- Other ports by having the BRE Pipeline Component set an Operation.
- From Orchestrations set via the Operation name from the Logical Port.

Answer (score -1):

My vote goes to Johns-305, if it truly is a 1-1 routing scenario...meaning rcvLocation A will always route to destination A - then just scale out your receive locations to separate receive ports and subscribe the send ports accordingly.

Now, if you are doing content driven routing, meaning something within the message dictates where the message is going, then you could do the orchestration route...but that would probably be overkill. I would create a  schema for the flatfile, promote whatever field will be used to route the message using a property schema, and subscribe the send ports to that.

Hope this helps!